# Update Linked List Top Entry

Tags: c

I'm faced the challenge of creating an algorithm to insert into the top of a Linked List. I have set a pointer to keep track of the top of the list.

```
#include "Entry.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct entry list;
    struct entry *listPtr = &list;

    list.value = 100;
    n1.value = 200;
    n2.value = 300;
    n3.value = 400;

    initList(&list);

    struct entry insert;
    insert.value = 1000;

    update(&insert, &n2);

    return 0;
}
```

The exercise suggest that I can use the update method to insert a new entry at the front of the list. How can I accomplish this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
}n1, n2, n3, end;

void initList(struct entry *list)
{
    list->next = &n1;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = &end;
    end.value = 0;
}

void update(struct entry *insert, struct entry *after)
{
    insert->next = after->next;
    after->next = insert;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If you check whether `after` is a null pointer or not, you can easily adapt the insert function to prepend to the list.

Comment: No… I'm a novice. Teaching myself how to program. I'm currently reading Programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan. My interest is OS internals so its imperative to learn C.

Comment: Teach youself how to use your debugger. Do it now, before you write any more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the `update` function to

```
struct entry *update(struct entry *insert, struct entry *before, struct entry *after)
{
    insert->next = after;
    if (before != NULL)
    {
        before->next = insert;
        return before;
    }
    return insert;
}
```

where `insert` is the entry to insert, `before` is the node before the one inserted, and `after` is the node after the one inserted. The function returns the new entry if it is being inserted as the first entry, and `before` otherwise.

To prepend to a list, use

```
list_to_prepend_to = update(node_to_insert, NULL, list_to_prepend_to);
```

For example, in your code, you could use

```
listPtr = update(&insert, NULL, &list);

while (listPtr)
{
    printf("%d\n", listPtr->value);
    listPtr = listPtr->next;
}
```

to prepend an entry to the list and print the list out. To insert in the middle of a list, you don't need the return value:

```
update(&insert, &list, &n1);
```

This will make `insert` the second entry in your list.

Comment: So I'm passing the following arguments to update: new node to insert at the top of the list, NULL, and the list to be updated. However the top of my list is not being updated with the new node.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing address of n2 to the update function. n2 is not the top of the list element. This will insert an element b/w n2 and end. 
To insert element after first element the top call-

update(&insert, &list);

To prepend a new element to the list-

struct entry new_element;

new_element.next = &list;

new_element.value = some_value;